# Excel connection to other Excel file

Tags: excel

I have 1 Master Excel Workbook - Results (Where all my data is in.) and an other Workbook where I want to do my analytics.

I start of by opening both Excel Workbooks. Put my formula in my analytic workbook.

Als long as both workbooks are open the data comes through. But as soon as I close my Master Excel Workbook the data is gone.

When both files are open I'm using this formula:

```
=IFERROR((COUNTIFS('[Results 2015-2016.xlsx]Results'!$E:$E;2015;'[Results 2015-2016.xlsx]Results'!$AN:$AN;"Completed";'[Results 2015-2016.xlsx]Results'!$J:$J;3;'[Results 2015-2016.xlsx]Results'!$K:$K;A3))+(COUNTIFS('[Results 2015-2016.xlsx]Results'!$E:$E;2015;'[Results 2015-2016.xlsx]Results'!$AN:$AN;"Completed";'[Results 2015-2016.xlsx]Results'!$J:$J;3;'[Results 2015-2016.xlsx]Results'!$L:$L;A3));"-")
```

When I close the Results Workbook I get this formula:

```
=IFERROR((COUNTIFS('C:\Users\Magali\Desktop\[Results 2015-2016.xlsx]Results'!$E:$E;2015;'C:\Users\Magali\Desktop\[Results 2015-2016.xlsx]Results'!$AN:$AN;"Completed";'C:\Users\Magali\Desktop\[Results 2015-2016.xlsx]Results'!$J:$J;3;'C:\Users\Magali\Desktop\[Results 2015-2016.xlsx]Results'!$K:$K;A3))+(COUNTIFS('C:\Users\Magali\Desktop\[Results 2015-2016.xlsx]Results'!$E:$E;2015;'C:\Users\Magali\Desktop\[Results 2015-2016.xlsx]Results'!$AN:$AN;"Completed";'C:\Users\Magali\Desktop\[Results 2015-2016.xlsx]Results'!$J:$J;3;'C:\Users\Magali\Desktop\[Results 2015-2016.xlsx]Results'!$L:$L;A3));"-")
```

Is there a way that I can work on my analytics worksheet without having to open teh Results worksheet?

Comment: This would happen if the Master workbook was pulling in data from a data connection that was set to delete data when the workbook is closed. I forget the exact setting but it's something like that. Any chance that's what's happening?

Comment: No Idea, been looking for this setting but can't find it anywhere

Comment: To find out if Master is using a data connection to pull data into a table, try looking in DATA> CONNECTIONS.